# Does TideSDK have any image manipulation capabilities?

Tags: tidesdk

I can't seem to see any image handling detail on the [TideSDK API](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api). Is it possible to do image manipulation?

Comment: Depends on what you call image manipulation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TideSDK API itself provides no methods for image manipulation so far. We will upgrade TideSDK to use the latest version of webkit with TideSDK 1.4 in october to give you full HTML5 and CSS3 support, along with the HTML5 Canvas, which you can use for javascript image processing.

Until then, you can try and do image manipulation with PHPs image functions, since in the currently used PHP version, GDlib v 2.0.34 is bundled.
Find the function docs here: http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Comment: That's what I thought. :) I just wanted to know if there was an undocumented way aside from the PHP approach. BTW, I realized you were the same one who authored https://github.com/Paratron/Titanium-Autocomplete. Is there any chance of that PhpStorm library being updated to the latest SDK version?

Comment: Sure, we already have a guide about that in [our documentation](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/ide_autocompletion)

Comment: Any news about svg or canvas support in TideSDK ?

Comment: Hey, yes - will propably never come. The team abandoned TideSDK. :(